# Android webview location redirect

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation, location

In my app I am trying to get the location of the device. If location services are on the app works fine. But if the location services are of in android I want the app to show a message that location services are off and prompt to enter address. My code is

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(init_pos,showerror);
        }
        else {

            window.open("Location.aspx", '_self', location = true);
        }

        function showerror(error) {
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    window.open("Location.aspx", '_self', location = true);
                break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    window.open("Location.aspx", '_self', location = true);
                break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    window.open("Location.aspx", '_self', location = true);
                break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    window.open("Location.aspx", '_self', location = true);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    function init_pos(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        long = position.coords.longitude;

        window.open("home1.aspx?lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + long, '_self', location = true);

    }
```

This code is working in local computers chrome but not in android device.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check whether your android devices's GPS enabled or not then you can use below snippet.

```
private LocationManager locManager;
locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
//GPS enabled       }
else
{
//GPS not enabled
}
```

And i can't get anything out of the posted code to get current location.
For better understanding have a look at this  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/